# How to prove a relation of conditional expectation?

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-probability

If $\mathcal G,\mathcal H$ are two fields with $\mathcal G \supset \mathcal H$ and if $\mathbb E(Z|\mathcal G),\mathbb E(Z|\mathcal H)$ have the same distribution, then why we can prove $\mathbb E(\mathbb E(Z|\mathcal G)\mathbb E(Z|\mathcal H))={\mathbb E(\mathbb E(Z|\mathcal H))}^{2}$?

Comment: To clarify, are you wanting to prove $=\left[\Bbb{E}(\Bbb{E}(Z|\mathcal{H}))\right]^2$ or $=\Bbb{E}(\left[\Bbb{E}(Z|\mathcal{H})\right]^2)$?

Answer (score 2):

Since $H \subset G$, we have that
$$  E(E(Z \vert  G) \vert H) = E(Z \vert H). $$
So
$$ E(E(Z \vert  G) E(Z \vert H) ) = E(E(E(Z \vert  G) \vert H) E(Z \vert H) ) = E( [ E(Z \vert H)]^2 ) $$

Comment: it's not enough maybe.

Comment: Could you please explain more details? @roger